# return errors from web api 2 account register

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to use the account controller in the MVC project to call the register account method in a WebApi 2 account controller. All works fine but I cant figure out how to return errors back to the MVC project such as: "password must contain Upper case and lower case" etc.

ASP.NET MVC account controller register:

```
//
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var response =
            await
                ApiRequest.PostAsync(String.Format("{0}/api/v1/account/register", "http://localhost:12345"), model);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }
            // Add errors

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

ApiRequest class:

```
public static class ApiRequest
{
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string uri, object item)
    {
        StringContent content = new StringContent(await Json.SerializeAsync(item));
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json");

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return await client.PostAsync(new Uri(uri), content);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string uri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return await client.GetAsync(new Uri(uri));
        }
    }

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutAsync(string uri, object item)
    {
        StringContent content = new StringContent(await Json.SerializeAsync(item));
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json");

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return await client.PutAsync(new Uri(uri), content);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteAsync(string uri, object id)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return await client.DeleteAsync(new Uri(String.Format("{0}/{1}", uri, id)));
        }
    }
}

public static class HttpResponseMessageExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> DeserialiseContentAsync<T>(this HttpResponseMessage message)
        where T : class
    {

        return await Json.DeserialiseAsync<T>(await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```

Web API 2 account controller register:

```
//
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = model.Username,
            Email = model.Email,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName
        };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (result.Errors != null)
            {
                foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                }
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }

        // Send email verification
        //string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

        //var callbackUrl = new Uri(Url.Link("ConfirmEmail", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }));

        //await
        //    UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account",
        //        "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

        Uri locationHeader = new Uri(Url.Link("GetUserById", new { id = user.Id }));

        return Created(locationHeader, user);
    }
```

GetErrorResult code:

```
private IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (result.Errors != null)
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // No ModelState errors are available to send, so just return an empty BadRequest.
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (string error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }
```

Im new to MVC and WebApi and have mainly been following tutorials, this is assume is basic stuff but i cant find a solution anywhere. I have separated the WebApi from the project intentionally so I can learn how these processes work better.

I'd like the solution not to be in javascript.

I'm assuming all subsequent requests will need to have a bearer token attached to the httpclient but i think this will be in another question.

Thanks in advance for any help on this

Comment: On your return  return GetErrorResult(result); I think you should do something like return  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, GetErrorResult(result)); . I am not 100% sure of this

Comment: are the api controller and mvc controller in the same project? if so, why don't you simply use UserManager to create the user in the mvc controller?

Comment: they are in separate projects with the intention to test this on separate machines

Comment: Can you add details about `APIRequest` class?

Comment: I've added the entire ApiRequest class in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All works fine but I cant figure out how to return errors back to the MVC project such as: "password must contain Upper case and lower case" etc.

You can send custom message in BadRequest() method overload. When you perform custom validation on Model just return a custom message.

```
 if (ValidatePasswordPolicy(model.Password))
     {
        return BadRequest("password must contain Upper case and lower case.");
     }
```

#### Update:

There's a difference in `ModelState` validation of `Asp.net mvc app` and `WebAPI`. When you're using `ModelState` to put errors in `WebAPI` then you have to properly handle the response. Proper handling means the response is succeeded or not. If not then are there `ModelState` errors or other error. Below snippet will show you how to deserialize the error to `anonymous object` and check if there are model state errors or other error. In case of `ModelState` errors you can simply add them to your `Asp.net mvc Model` and return the view with model to update UI with errors.

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
}
else
{
    var httpErrorObject = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var anonymousErrorObject =
        new { message = "", ModelState = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() };

    // Deserialize:
    var deserializedErrorObject =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(httpErrorObject, anonymousErrorObject);

    // Check if there are actually model errors
    if (deserializedErrorObject.ModelState != null)
    {
        var errors =
            deserializedErrorObject.ModelState
                                    .Select(kvp => string.Join(". ", kvp.Value));
        for (int i = 0; i < errors.Count(); i++)
        {
            // Add errors to ModelState in Asp.net mvc app

        }
    }
    // Othertimes, there may not be Model Errors:
    else
    {
        var error =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(httpErrorObject);
        foreach (var kvp in error)
        {
            // Now this is not model error so you can throw exception 
            // or any custom action what ever you like
        }
    }
}
```

There's a detailed article about handling errors from WebAPI in Asp.net mvc App [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825274/ASP-NET-Web-Api-Unwrapping-HTTP-Error-Results-and).

Comment: I'm just trying something like this now, would this work with a list of error messages. My problem is actually reading it from the mvc app `HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: This is only to send custom message with response. I think for list of errors you should Add errors to ModelState and return `BadRequest(modelState);`.

Comment: sure, i've modified my web api register to use modelstate. How would I extract the errors from the `HttpResponseMessage` on the mvc side, Deserialise to ModelState type?

Comment: @AdamH You actually mentioned couple of things together which is my your question wasn't so clear in first read. I got your problem now.. see my updated answer.

Comment: apologies for the poorly constructed question, I wasn't sure on which end the problem was. Your solution works perfectly, thanks

Comment: Awesome!! You should also read the article I mentioned to understand the solution in detail.